# Directly powering a 3 VDC motor with a small solar panel

Tags: dc-motor, solar-cell

I am trying to power a [DC motor](http://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Robotics/M260.pdf) directly using a [solar panel.](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Seeed%20Technology/313070001_Web.pdf)

I measured the output DC voltage of the solar panel. It is well above 3 V in ambient light (3.8 to 4.5 VDC), but when I connect it to the DC motor nothing happens.

I had a previous setup in which I used the output voltage of the solar panel to steer the PWM port of an Arduino, but this time I wanted to try it directly and make the setup much simpler.

Am I missing a very basic principle here?

Comment: Max power is 3W, 540mA from the solar panel (that's MAX, so you'll be lucky to get half of that). No idea what the motor will need, that is not a motor datasheet, that is a document with a few numbers on it. Measure the resistance of the motor, that'll give you the information to work out the required starting current. My guess is that would be around 1A, so way more than your PV panel can supply. So you aren't providing the current to turn the motor.

Comment: Based on the datasheet numbers I would expect this to just work. Can you measure the voltage and current while the motor is connected to the solar panel? (remember: current measurement in series with the circuit, voltage measurement in parallel)

Comment: You may be running afoul of the motor's high start-up current. Try charging an electrolytic capacitor with the solar panel before connecting the motor - something like 470uf/10V (a 1000uf is OK too). Capacitor is simply wired permanently parallel with solar panel - motor connected to that through a series switch. Ensure the capacitor polarity is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The Locked Rotor Amerage of the motor is 800mA.   This is the current the motor will draw when it is just starting to rotate.  Motors need a lot of current to start, but they don't need very high voltage to start.

The spec output of the solar panel is 500mA.

Now to the panel, the motor will appear as a dead short.  A solar panel is a *peculiar exception* to the usual rules, in that you are allowed to short its output.  It will flow its maximum possible current, which will remain a reasonable value and is declared as **I<sub>sc</sub>**.  This panel doesn't specify an I<sub>sc</sub> (cheap?  Or maybe 500mA is *it?*)

But you can ascertain it by testing, by doing what you normally never do: setting your DVM for "amps" and connecting both leads to the solar panel output.  You only do this on solar panels!!! And only when you know  I<sub>sc</sub> is within the range of the meter!

Once you are looking at an *actual, measured* I<sub>sc</sub> number, I believe you will see why the motor isn't starting. You can troubleshoot from there, either by getting the panel into more light, paralleling more units, or getting your money back if the listing was a lie.

*At the risk of stating the obvious: your eyes auto-adjust to many environments. Solar panels do not. A "seems bright to me" well-lit workspace may have 1330 lumens per metre.  The sun is 133,000 lumens per metre or 100 times brighter. Testing indoors Won't Work.*

Comment: I just tried this and I'm getting only 5.4mA from the panel from shining on it with a couple of night lamps and a phone flashlight. I know it might sounds low-tech/hacked together but the goal would be to let the kids shine on the panel with their phone first and then try it outside with actual solar power. 
but it seems that I'll have to try to measure the I_sc outside this afternoon.

Comment: @Fabrice_M you really, really, really, really, really, really do not understand the energy level differences between sunlight and artificial light.  Really. You have *no idea* how dramatically different it is.  Learn more about lux and lumens and sunlight.  Really.  I can't emphasize this more.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the links they helped a lot. The simple answer is you need more light. It should work when you have enough light. However if you get to much light you can fry your motor by over voltage. Also place a flyback diode across the motor, any 1N400x would be fine. The reason for this is the motor is inductive. When turned off the inductor (motor windings) will collapse, reversing the polarity on the leads and the voltage will rise until limited by external circurity. This design will be limited as to when it will work. Also you can possibly fry the motor when it is getting a low voltage and not rotating. For proving a principle it would be ok, for a long term solution I would not recommend it for reliability reasons.

Comment: @user253751 My understanding is that in normal operation, a solar panel is forward biased; if inductive kickback happened, then the solar panel would become reverse biased and it would fail to conduct.

Comment: @user253751 'Inductive "kickback" would force the panel to "output" more current than it "wants" to' – yeah, and a solar panel is a big diode that's putting positive charge out of its anode. Normally, diodes don't "want" to put _any_ positive charge out of their anodes, but when light shines on a solar panel, that generates charge carrier pairs that produce current "the wrong way." Only a limited number of them are created, though, so if you try to force more current through the solar panel, then you just turn it into a more-or-less ordinary reverse-biased diode.

Comment: @user253751 As far as I know, most diodes get damaged when you exceed their reverse breakdown voltage, so I would guess that the same is true of solar panels. But my guess could very well be wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139530/discussion-between-tanner-swett-and-user253751).